# Fluent NHibernate & one-to-one

Tags: fluent-nhibernate, one-to-one

For a (very) long time I've been looking for an example on how to correctly implement a *one-to-one* mapping with Fluent NHibernate.

Most resources I find say:

> I think you mean a many-to-one

However no one actually gives an example on how to correctly implement the one-to-one relation.

So, **could you give an one-to-one mapping example with Fluent NHibernate**?

Note: I'm not interested in people saying "what's your model, you might actually need *HasMany*". No, thanks, I simply need a *one-to-one* example.

To be more precise, **I know the syntax**. That's the only thing I could find by searching by myself. What I'm looking for is a more complete example, including a ((very) simple) database setup, and the whole mapping, of all entities that participate in the relationship, which I think would have reasonable size for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I've solved my problem.

I've also written a somewhat detailed article on this problem, that you can find at: http://brunoreis.com/tech/fluent-nhibernate-hasone-how-implement-one-to-one-relationship/index.html

You will find a scenario in which we want a one-to-one relationship, the database schema as we would like it, the code of the model as it needs to be to meet NHibernate requirements, and the *Fluent* mapping that corresponds to the situation.

Comment: Fixed. I accidentally broke the link 2 days ago when I changed a few settings. Thanks for reporting!

Comment: Please post the relevant content in the answer. Link-only answers are discouraged.

Comment: @BrunoReis Thanks but your article has broken links to images :(

Answer (score 3):

```
these are the two classes.

public class A
{
  public virtual int Id {get;set;}
  public virtual string P1 {get;set;}
  public virtual string P2 {get;set;}
  public virtual string P3 {get;set;}
  public virtual B child { get; set; }
}

public class B
{
  public virtual int Id {get;set;}
  public virtual string P4 {get;set;}
  public virtual string P5 {get;set;}
  public virtual string P6 {get;set;}
  public virtual A parent;
}
```

this should be added in the fluent configuration.

```
public AMap()
    {
      /* mapping for id and properties here */
      HasOne(x => x.child)
          .Cascade.All();
    }

    public BMap()
    {
      /* mapping for id and properties here */
      References(x => x.parent)
          .Unique();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

[This is the best example](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2009/04/19/nhibernate-mapping-ltone-to-onegt.aspx) I've seen. Hopefully it meets your needs.

Comment: Please put the most important information in the post. Link-only answers are discouraged.

Answer (score -2):

`HasOne(x => x.Prop)`

Comment: This is not an example, this is just the syntax. I'm looking for a some more contextual example, explaining the DB setup as well.

Comment: You said you didn't want a HasMany, that implied to me that you actually know what a one-to-one is to be able to choose it over something else.

Comment: yes, I know what a one-to-one is, but I always run into problems with the mapping of IDs, autogenerated IDs.

Comment: Create your mappings, generate the schema, compare the results to how you normally do it.