# Mapping weak entity

Tags: c#, fluent-nhibernate

I got the following weak entity (can not exist without WikiPage):

```
CREATE TABLE WikiPageTree 
(
    PageId int NOT NULL, 
    Title nvarchar(1000) NOT NULL, 
    Lineage nvarchar(1000) NOT NULL,
)
```

Where `PageId` is a FK to `Page.Id`. It's a 1-1 mapping.

How should the mapping look like? I can't figure out how to specify the `Id` mapping that fluent-nhibernate requires.

I tried the following as suggested in the answer by @WillDaBest:

```
public class WikiPageTreeMap : ClassMap<WikiPageTreeNode>
{
    public WikiPageTreeMap()
    {
        Table("WikiPageTree");
        LazyLoad();

        Id(Reveal.Member<WikiPageTreeNode>("PageId")).GeneratedBy.Foreign("Page");
        HasOne(x=>x.Page).Constrained().ForeignKey();

        //Id(x => x.Page).Column("PageId");
        //References(x => x.Page).Column("PageId");
        Map(x => x.Path).Column("Title").Not.Nullable().Length(1000);
        Map(x => x.Lineage).Column("Lineage").Not.Nullable().Length(1000);
    }
}
```

But it gives me the error

> {"Must declare the scalar variable \"@p0\"."}

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fluent NHibernate & one-to-one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2071274/fluent-nhibernate-one-to-one)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might help with mapping a one-to-one relationship in Fluent nHibernate: http://brunoreis.com/tech/fluent-nhibernate-hasone-how-implement-one-to-one-relationship/